# Firebase set object in firestore never catches errors

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Using Firebase firestore database I created a function which creates or updates a member profile represented as JSON object. Creation und Updating works fine but I also want to do correct errorhandling. My code is based on the official documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data but the error case is never called, e.g. I disable internet connectivity or alter the collection name to a non existing one.
Does anyone know how to catch errors using firebase's set-method?

```
collection("member")
.doc(member.authUID)
.set(member).then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
// dispatch(success_action)..
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
// dispatch(error_action)..
});
```

Comment: Though both part of Firebase, `google-cloud-firestore` and `firebase-realtime-database` are separate databases. Please only tag your question with the tag for the database you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have two separate cases here:

1. Writing without an internet connection is not seen as a failure for Cloud Firestore, as it can work without an internet connection. It has a full local database where it can store the data, and can continue working offline for a reasonable amount of time.
2. A collection is automatically created when a document is written to it. So when you write to a non-existing collection, you're simply creating that collection.

The common case for the error handler to be called is if your [server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview) reject the write operation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, It's awesome what a large number of features firebase automatically covers.